# How to access elements of a vector, where the vectors are mapped with a character 'key' in unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map where the keys are characters and the values are vectors:
`unordered_map<char,vector<int> > table;`

I'm trying to print the keys and their values:

```
for(unordered_map<char,vector<int> > ::const_iterator iter = table.begin(); iter != table.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout<<iter->first<< "\t";
    for(vector<int> :: const_iterator iter1 = iter->second.begin(); iter1 != iter->second.end(); ++iter1)
    {
        cout<<(iter->second)[iter1];
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

But I'm getting these errors which I'm unable to solve:

```
15_09_2015.cpp: In function 'void printTable()':
15_09_2015.cpp:169:24: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const std::vector<int>' and 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}')
    cout<<(iter->second)[iter1];
                        ^
15_09_2015.cpp:169:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:64:0,
                 from 15_09_2015.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:770:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = int&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
       operator[](size_type __n)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:770:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'std::vector<int>::size_type {aka unsigned int}'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:785:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) const [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_reference = const int&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
       operator[](size_type __n) const
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:785:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int>::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >}' to 'std::vector<int>::size_type {aka unsigned int}'
```

What did I do wrong? How can I print the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator[]` expects the parameter with the type `std::vector::size_type`, so an `iterator` can't be used as its argument. You can change the loop to:

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < iter->second.size(); i++)
{
    cout<<(iter->second)[i];
}
```

Or you can just `cout<<*iter1;` to print the value pointed by the iterator.

```
for(vector<int> :: const_iterator iter1 = iter->second.begin(); iter1 != iter->second.end(); ++iter1)
{
    cout<<*iter1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the value from an iterator, just dereference it with `*`, like what you would do with a pointer. But there's no point in explicitly using iterators here. Just use a range-based for loop.

```
for(const auto& p : table)
{
    cout << p.first << "\t";
    for(const auto& i : p.second)
    {
        cout << i;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: When should we use iterators?

Comment: @DharitParikh When you need to do something more complicated than "do X to every element in the range".

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code as below to print all values,

```
for(auto iter = table.begin(); iter != table.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout<<iter->first<< "\t";
    for(auto iter1 = iter->second.begin(); iter1 != iter->second.end(); ++iter1)
    {
        cout<<*iter1;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```